# Cannot debug my STM32 CubeIDE project anymore, but code works without J-Link

Tags: gdb, stm32f7, segger-jlink, stm32cubeide

I somehow have fallen in the state where I cannot start in debug mode my project in CubeIDE and J-Link. The code compiles, flash is written, but then instead of stopping on the first instruction in my main function in `main.c`, I get stuck in the Disassembly part of the project.

In title bar it says *"Source not found"* and in working window it says:

> Break at address "0x20011b88" with no debug information available, or outside of program code.

Disassembly on this address shows:

```
20011b88:   bkpt    0x0000
```

but step into pops up the window with:

> Failed to execute MI command: -exec-step 1 Error message from debugger back end; Cannot find bounds of current function

I must be missing something obvious here, and will appreciate any guidance.
Also some pointers, where to study, how project debuging is started in details, will be welcomed.

Comment: Did you try debugging you application outside the CubeIDE, i.e. using the JLink GDB server and the GDB executable ? Are you using a Windows or a Linux system for development ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for response... I'm using Windows and Cube IDE. I could try GDB, but need to learn how to do it... Any pointer where to learn ?

Comment: Ok, I can show you. What is the exact `stm32f7` MCU model you are targeting ?

Comment: Could you also provide the compile/link options you are using in your project ?

Comment: Not sure if that helps, but if I click on Reset in Debug menu, it jumps to main. I could understand that maybe adding reset command to some script would help, but still it bugs me why it worked before...

Comment: Same old story, you may have modified the project settings at one point without even noticing. Since this IDE is Eclipse-based, you could manage the project configuration files using git/svn, along with your source code.  If something stops working, you can see what changed since the last, stable version. Doing this did help me a couple of times already. Since this seems to be an IDE-related issue, there is not much I can do.

Comment: Thanks will take a look on git...

Comment: For a given project, here are the directories/files you could track: `.settings`, `.mxproject`, `.cproject`, `.project`. This is probably better than to close the project prior to perform any `git` commit/compare operations - my two cents.